# Extract string until dot before space

Tags: c#, string

I have the following line:

```
Id.Action.AddToken Host Token
Id.Action.AddTokenFile path\to\file.ext
```

I want to match anything that comes before the last dot that comes before the first whitespace. So, in this case, I want to get back:

```
Id.Action.   (including the dot)
```

I already have tried a `([^\s]+)` regex to find the first space but how do I get the dot before it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get better performance (and arguably more readable code) if you *don't* use a regex:

```
// First, search for the space, starting from the beginning of the string
int space = str.IndexOf(' ');
// Then, search backwards from the space until you find a dot
int dot = str.LastIndexOf('.', space);
// Get the substring (+ 1 to include the dot)
var result = str.Substring(0, dot + 1);
```

Comment: This works, thx. I didn't try `LastIndexOf` because I thought it would give me the dot in file.ext